# Cos'è una "finestra spericolata"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> La luce pioveva di sghembo da una finestra **spericolata** e il suo viso s'increspava come un'acqua morta: brividi sul ciglio, agli angoli della bocca, per le narici: da ragazzo lo chiamavano il coniglio.

Nei dizionari ho trovato che "spericolato" significa *che si espone a pericoli con temerarietà*. Tuttavia, non capisco il senso di "finestra spericolata" nel brano sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Ci sono, prima e/o dopo, altri riferimenti al luogo dove si svolge questa scena? "Finestra spericolata" mi fa pensare a una finestra esposta, sporta in avanti, o posta molto in alto...

Comment: @Benedetta: La scena si svolge nella sagrestia della chiesa di Santa Maria in Aquiro a Roma.

Comment: Sarebbe interessante chiedersi, anche, cosa sia un 'acqua morta'.

Comment: Non so dove fosse, in quel periodo, la sacrestia di questa chiesa. Se non ci sono altri riferimenti al luogo, terrei, come propone anche @mrnld, il significato di "esposta", immaginando che usando "spericolata" Anna Banti volesse dare anche un'idea di pericolo.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: per "acqua morta" credo si intenda uno specchio d'acqua ferma, non mossa (il viso descritto, infatti, ha pochi movimenti)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Potrebbe essere semplicemente un modo (piuttosto contorto) per dire che la finestra è [esposta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esposto/), nel senso seguente:

> [Esposto:] Di persona o **cosa che si offra liberamente a un’azione esterna**: *essere e. all’aria, alle correnti;giardino e. al sole; una torre e. a tutti i venti;* anche di spazio o ambiente situato in luogo aperto e quindi soggetto ai venti e al sole: *un prato molto e.; casa con la facciata e. (cioè rivolta) a mezzogiorno; edificio, appartamento bene o male e.*

Concludo ciò osservando che tra i [sinonimi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spericolarsi_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) di *spericolarsi* (di cui *spericolato* è participio passato), compare proprio la voce *esporsi*:

> spericolarsi v. intr. pron. [der. di pericolo, col pref. s- (nel sign. 5)] (io mi sperìcolo, ecc.), non com. - [esporsi temerariamente a un pericolo, a un rischio] ≈ arrischiarsi, osare, rischiare. ↓ **esporsi**.